# In this simple active Baxandall tone control, what's Rin function?

Tags: tone-control

In the following diagram, what's Rin purpose? Is it to set or limit gain?

[image]

[image]

UPDATE

Changing the Rin value shows this:

[image]

Comment: what happens when you change the Rin value?

Comment: All my Baxandall circuits say, "The signal source must be a low impedance" and are driven from the output of a preamp opamp.

Comment: @jsotola I added a graphic showing what happens when fiddling with Rin

Comment: @AramAlvarez It minimizes (flattens) the frequency response variation when both pots are in the half-way (neutral) position. Have you tried to analyze the circuit? It's got 11 nodes (if including Vin and Vout.) It's not a terrible pain to plug it into a symbolic solver.